# @Repository class not getting Autowired in my test class

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired, dao

I have DAO marked with @Repository annotation in the main folder. I need to access this DAO in my test class. I'm using @Autowire for this but the DAO object is throwing a null pointer exception.
Please help as I'm relatively new to Spring boot

Comment: Without code is not easy to know what happen. Also, if you are using mockito for tests, have you included `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` ? By the way, are you mocking your DAO class?

Comment: When you are running the tests, the beans in the application context will not be autowired. You can mock the repository using Mockito and use the mocks.

Comment: I'm autowiring my DAO class and mocking the session factory that is being used in it. Still it's throwing a null pointer exception

Comment: Can you share the code and the error log ?